# Excel Forumla/VBA to skip blank columns for calculation

Tags: vba, excel

I have a particular data set that consists of information for projects our company works on. Each project can go through five different statuses and we have a column that records each date the project is put into that particular status.

Now for the Excel part. We are trying to calculate the days in each status and find the total project time. The total is easy to do, because I can use network days between the project submitted date and the project go live date. The statuses, however, are giving me issues because sometimes a project will skip a status, leaving the date field empty. So what happens is a project goes from status B to status D, the formula for days in status "B" look for a date in column "C" to use as the second date in a NETWORKDAYS formula. When it is empty, the IF argument tells the formula to use TODAY() as the second date. What I need it to do is  the search the columns to the right (within the given range of A:E for that row) and use that date if it exists. If not, then it can default to TODAY() because this would be an "active" project that has not moved on.

```
=IF(IF(OR([@STALLED]<>"",[@CANCELED]<>""),"",IF([@INTAKEDATE]="","",IF([@SCOPEATE]="",NETWORKDAYS([@INTAKEDATE],TODAY()),(NETWORKDAYS([@STATUSADATE],[@SCOPEATE])))))<0,"",(IF(OR([@STALLED]<>"",[@CANCELED]<>""),"",IF([@INTAKEDATE]="","",IF([@SCOPEATE]="",NETWORKDAYS([@INTAKEDATE],TODAY()),(NETWORKDAYS([@STATUSADATE],[@SCOPEATE])))))))
```

This is done for each of the statuses so the table looks something like this:

PROJECTID   PROJECTNAME    INTAKEDATE  SCOPEATE   BUILDDATE   TESTDATE  GOLIVEDATE  INTAKEDAYS   SCOPEDAYS   BUILDDAYS   TESTDAYS

If there is any Macro or better formula someone could help me figure out, I'd appreciate it. There is also another field that gives the current status or if the project is considered live if that helps at all. I have excel-block right now and cant think of anything that makes sense for this.

Comment: I hadnt considered using `MAX`, though I think in my case I'd need to use `MIN` since the days would skew if it skipped over the next, immediate status date. But maybe something like this should work: 
SCOPEDAYS:
    =IF(IF(OR([@STALLED]<>"",[@CANCELED]<>""),"",IF([@BUILDDATE]="",NETWORKDAYS([@SCOPEDATE],MIN([@BUILDDATE]:[@GOLIVEDATE],(NETWORKDAYS([@STATUSADATE],[@SCOPEATE])))))<0,"",(IF(OR([@STALLED]<>"",[@CANCELED]<>""),"",IF([@INTAKEDATE]="","",F([@BUILDDATE]="",NETWORKDAYS([@SCOPEDATE],MIN([@BUILDDATE]:[@GOLIVEDATE])))))))

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out using `MIN` and by adjusting the `IF` formulas a bit. Whoever it was that posted about `MAX` earlier, really helped me out getting me down this path. Kudos to you sir/madam.

I had to add the check to see if SCOPEDATE=BUILDDATE because without that it was returning 1 if the dates matched, with was adding one more day when compared to running the networkdays from INTAKEDATE to GOLIVEDATE.

```
=IF(OR([@STALLED]<>"",[@CANCELED]<>""),"",
     IF([@SCOPEDATE]="","",
     IF([@SCOPEDATE]=[@BUILDDATE],0,
     IF(NETWORKDAYS([@SCOPEDATE],(MIN([@BUILDDATE],[@TESTDATE],[@GOLIVEDATE])))<0,NETWORKDAYS([@SCOPEDATE],TODAY()),NETWORKDAYS([@SCOPEDATE],(MIN([@BUILDDATE],[@TESTDATE],[@GOLIVEDATE])))))))
```

I hope this is helpful for someone else.